# When deploying Heroku app I get DisallowedHost at / - But I have added the URL to ALLOWED_HOSTS

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

**DisallowedHost at /
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '#.herokuapp.com'. You may need to add '#.herokuapp.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.**

But I have added both '#.herokuapp.com' and 'www.#.herokuapp.com' into ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py

Everything is up to date on GitHub and when I change anything in settings.py locally and git add, commit and then run '$ git push heroku master' it detects the insertion/deletion. Builds and deploys the Heroku app successfully. So it should be reading the ALLOWED_HOSTS also, but it's the same annoying error every time!

[DisallowedHost at / (Error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqW1S.png)

Really pulling my hair out with this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED:

There was another file in the settings directory called production.py. Its settings override what is defined in settings.py.

Solution is to add the domain in the ALLOWED_HOSTS there.

Answer (score 0):

Try running in this format

`['www.app_name.herokuapp.com']`  # Fully qualified domain

`['.herokuapp.com']`  # Subdomain wildcard, matches example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

`['*']`  # all domain whitelist